# Prevent loss of changes when merging parallel git branches

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am following the below strategy for managing my code and deployment:

I have 3 servers `qa`, `staging` and `prod`.

I have 4 main branches: `Qa` ( which gets deployed on Qa server) `Staging` ( which gets deployed on staging server) `release` ( which is replica of master branch) and `master` branch ( which gets deployed on prod server and is most stable code.

We follow the strategy of working in featured branch for every tickets.

Below is the steps:

1. `Release` branch is checkout from `master` branch.
2. Now every feature branch is checkout from `release` branch.
3. Once the feature is completed its merged to `QA` branch.
4. Thats feature is tested on `QA` server. Once approved its merged to `staging` branch and tested . Once verifies its merged to `release` branch.

Now what issue I am facing is that my code is getting overwritten when i am merging from a featured branch to `QA` branch.

Lets say there 2  developers who has checkout featured branch from `release` branch.

Now one has made some change in style.css and commited the code in featured branch and files a PR. The code get merged to `QA`.

Once the same thing is done by other developer some of the code gets deleted.

Please help how to get it resolved so that the code do not gets deleted when the code is merged by some other developer on same file.

Comment: Don’t you push with the `--force` parameter?

Comment: please provide an example of code being deleted at merge: the original code, changes of 1st developer, changes of second developer, code after merge.

Comment: You should change the title of the questions, and delete anything above "Lets say there 2 developers....". Probably you should just delete the question, because you ask about how does git merge work.

Comment: Git doesn't delete contents on its own. Either someone manually deleted content in one branch, which git then merges into your QA branch and thus it ends up deleted there as well, or someone edited/deleted content in one branch that conflicts with the changes introduced in QA and incorrectly resolves the merge conflict. Without knowing more about the changes merged into QA that deleted other changes nobody here can tell you what caused this, except that git didn't do it by itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the second merge, git merge would fail with a conflict, in which case your team will have to resolve the merge conflict. That way, no code gets deleted.